# Full globalization and localization

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I'm trying to integrate globlization in my asp.net core using two different ways in my views.

The first one, is the classic one, I have my resx files under the corresponding folder for each views and it's working.

The second one is the shared method, to have a based resx file to do not rewrite every translation in each views.

My problem is that i not able to work with the both at the same time.

Here my configuration in startup.cs :

```
// This method gets called by the runtime. 
// Use this method to add services to the container.
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{

    // Add framework services.
    services.AddMvc()
        .AddViewLocalization(
            opts => { opts.ResourcesPath = "Resources"; }
         )
        .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization();
}
```

If I remove the ressources path, the sharedRessources work but not the basic one.

```
// This method gets called by the runtime. 
// Use this method to add services to the container.
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{

    // Add framework services.
    services.AddMvc()
        .AddViewLocalization()
        .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization();
}
```

This is my view implementation for index

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Localization
@using Delphi.LicenseRenewal.WebApp.Resources

@inject IViewLocalizer Localizer
@inject IHtmlLocalizer<SharedResource> SharedLocalizer

<h1 class="title-color">@SharedLocalizer["Title"]</h1>
<h3 class="title-color">@Localizer["SubTitle"]</h3>
```

And i add too my project structure if is needed :

[image: Structure of ressources]

Comment: are you getting some kind of exception message?

Comment: no, my view display "Title" instead of the value. When I debug the code, the ressource manager don't find the shared files

Comment: I don't know if is the good solution, but after some investigations if i put my shared resx under Resources/Resources the both can work together